# How to tell compiler that two objects are of same - but unknown - class (with generics)?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

Please consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Object o1 = getObject(Math.random());
    Object o2 = getObject(Math.random());
    if (o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass()) { // two Cars or two Apples
      Comparable c1 = (Comparable) o1;
      Comparable c2 = (Comparable) o2;
      int x = c1.compareTo(c2); // unsafe
      System.out.println(x);
    )
  }

  public Object getObject(double d) { // given method that may not be changed
    if (d < 0.5) return (new Car()); // Car implements Comparable<Car>
    else return (new Apple()); // Apple implements Comparable<Apple>
  }

}
```

The code works (given the classes `Cat` and `Apple`) but the compiler warns for unsafe operations because I use `compareTo` without generics. I do not know how to fix this, however, because I have no idea how to specify that `c1` and `c2` are of the same - but unknown - type (in the `if` clause). Is there any way (besides using `@SuppressWarnings` of course) to fix this?

I am aware that there is a similar question here: [How to tell Java that two wildcard types are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730923/how-to-tell-java-that-two-wildcard-types-are-the-same)
But the answer given there seems to be specific to the context of the asker. For example, it uses a key-value map which does not exist in my context.

Answer (score 1):

Since the condition `if (o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass()))` guarantees that the two objects are of the same class,
it's safe to ignore the warning. You can suppress it.

However, since their type is `Object` at that point,
it's not safe to cast them to `Comparable`.
You can make it safer with some minor tweaks, to make them of class `Comparable`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparable<?> o1 = getComparable(Math.random());
    Comparable<?> o2 = getComparable(Math.random());
    if (o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass())) {
        // safe cast
        Comparable c1 = (Comparable) o1;
        Comparable c2 = (Comparable) o2;
        // safe comparison
        int x = c1.compareTo(c2);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>> getComparable(double d) {
    if (d < 0.5) return (new Car());
    return (new Apple());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In reality, the getObject() method is given by a library, so I have no control of it, otherwise I would follow your suggestion. I just don't like to have to suppress a warning; there should be a better way (but obviously there is not).

Comment: "guarantees that the two objects are of the same class, it's safe to ignore the warning" No it isn't. A class is not guaranteed to be comparable to itself from a type-safety point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that a `Comparable<Car>` and a `Comparable<Apple>` cannot be compared against each other, as `Comparable<T>` has the "comfortable" feature just comparing `T`s. And now we are paying for it.

For `.equals` this is not the case.

What we are trying

```
// WILL NOT WORK

if (o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass()) { // two Cars or two Apples
  int x = comparison(o1.getClass(), o1, o2);
  System.out.println(x);
)

static <T extends Comparable<T>> int comparison(Class<T> type, T o1, T o2) {
    return type.cast(o1).compareTo(type.cast(o2));
}
```

This is a feature of java, with a very minimally expressive type system.

Answer (score -1):

Update your methods to deal with `Comparable` objects rather than `Object` objects.

```
public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Comparable o1 = getObject(Math.random());
    Comparable o2 = getObject(Math.random());
    if (o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass()) { // two Cars or two Apples
      int x = o1.compareTo(o2);
      System.out.println(x);
    )
  }

  public Comparable getObject(double d) { // given method that may not be changed
    if (d < 0.5) return (new Car()); // Car implements Comparable<Car>
    else return (new Apple()); // Apple implements Comparable<Apple>
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Object o1 = getObject(Math.random());
    Object o2 = getObject(Math.random());
    if ( o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass() ) && o1 instanceof Comparable ) {
      int x = getObject(o1).compareTo(o2);
      System.out.println(x);
    }

  }

  public static Object getObject(double d) { // given method that may not be changed
    if (d < 0.5) return ( new Car() ); // Car implements Comparable<Car>
    else return ( new Apple() ); // Apple implements Comparable<Apple>
  }

  public static <T> Comparable<T> getObject(Object o) {
      return (Comparable<T>)o;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use instanceof operators. You can write it as:

```
if(c1 instanceof Integer && c2 instanceof Integer)
   int x = c.compareTo(c2);





or if(c1 instanceof String)
    String s = c1;
```

You can work this way.

Comment: @Aominè it's an example and if you look at this code, he is comparing int which is an instance of wrapper class Integer and if he understands this he can offcouse check for other instances aswell.  This should remove his warning because he was trying to assin value to int without checking their types.

Comment: yes lol i was writing something in prolog btw thanks , i will edit it.